# Change timestamp format in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am getting timestamp format as '01-APR-21 12.02.00.496677000 AM' from oracle, I want to change the format to load data into sql server column with datatype as datetime.

Current Input:   '01-APR-21 12.02.00.496677000 AM'
Expected Output : 2021-04-01 12:02:00.496

I need to write the code in oracle to change timestamp format

Thanks
Neha

Comment: The default format is defined by your session's `nls_timestamp_format`.  You could change that for the current session but it seems very weird that you care about the display format of a timestamp if you're moving it to a different database.  Any ETL tool should just move the data from a `timestamp` column to a `datetime` without worrying about what format the current session would use if it wanted to do an implicit conversion of the `timestamp` to a `varchar2`.

Comment: i cannot change anything in the oracle database as it it not owned by us. I am not using any ETL tool i have to load data into different database via mule4

Comment: You can change your session settings, that doesn't change anything in the database. If you are writing your own ETL process for extracting the data then you need to explain how you are doing it. If, for example, you're querying a table and writing the output to a text file that you later use to load into SQL Server, then you can set the session's format, or use `to_char()` with the format you require for each date/timestamp column. But we need to know what you are doing to be able to help you.

Comment: It seems unlikely that MuleSoft is unable to take a `timestamp` from an Oracle database and move it to a `datetime` in SQL Server without requiring an implicit conversion of the `timestamp` to a `varchar2`.  You could, of course, do an explicit `to_char` on the `timestamp` to convert it to a string in whatever format you want.  But, again, it seems unlikely that this step would be necessary.

Comment: The point is that format is an output property, not inherent in the data itself. You can alter your session (this does not change the database) to change the default output format, or you can use to_char to change the output format in a query, but these only affect how data is *displayed* as characters. Migrating data from `timestamp` in Oracle to `datetime` in SQL Server shouldn't care about character format output; the ETL tool should be able to perform a direct conversion from one datatype to the other.

Comment: there is no explict conversion happening. I loaded the oracle data into a diferent sql table where  date format was varchar and data got loaded as  '01-APR-21 12.02.00.496677000 AM'  . After this from my sql table only i am loadind data into my desired table where format is datetime, But there i am getting error as "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `TIMESTAMP` is a binary data format consisting of 7-20 bytes (century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute, second, up to 6 bytes for fractional seconds and up to 7 bytes for time zone information); it does **NOT** have a format.

## Why am I seeing the `TIMESTAMP` with a format?

You are seeing it with a format because whatever user interface you are using to access the database has decided that it is more useful to *display* the binary information as a formatted string rather than returning the raw byte values to you.

Typically, for SQL/Plus and SQL Developer, this is managed by the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter. Other user interfaces will have different mechanisms by which they manage the default format of dates and timestamps.

If you want to change the default for SQL/Plus (and SQl Developer) then you can use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9';
```

*(Or whatever format you would like.)*

## How can I format the `TIMESTAMP` value?

If you then want to *display* the timestamp with a format (remember, a `TIMESTAMP` is not stored with any format) then you want to use `TO_CHAR` to convert it to a string where it can have a format.

If you want to format the `TIMESTAMP` as a `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3` string then use:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR( your_timestamp_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3' )
FROM   your_table
```

## How can I convert a formatted string back to a `TIMESTAMP`?

From your comment:

> I loaded the oracle data into a different SQL table where date format was `varchar` and data got loaded as '01-APR-21 12.02.00.496677000 AM'

Use `TO_TIMESTAMP`:

```sql
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP( your_string_column, 'DD-MON-RR HH12:MI:SS.FF9 AM' )
FROM   your_table
```

*(Note: that this will convert your string to a binary `TIMESTAMP` and then whatever user interface you are using will use its rules on how to display it; and if the default format it is using is `DD-MON-RR HH12:MI:SS.FF9 AM` then the query above will look like it has done nothing; it has, the UI is just implicitly converting it back to a string to *display* it.)*

Comment: TO_CHAR( '01-APR-21 12.02.00.496677000 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3' ) is not working , i am getting error as ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: @NehaSingh - '01-APR-21 12.02.00.496677000 AM' is a string not a timestamp. As MTO said that expression is to convert an actual timestamp to a string. Use the `select to_timestamp()` statement to convert the other way.

Comment: Thanks you MTO and Alex